# Read JWT token in Spring Boot RouterFunction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, router

In Spring Boot Controller implementation we can get the `JwtAuthenticationToken` as a parameter in our method. Same token can be read, manipulated and validated for authorization like below

```
@PostMapping("/hello")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_Internal') or hasAuthority('ROLE_User')")
public Mono<String> testHello(JwtAuthenticationToken token) {
    log.info("token is " + token.getTokenAttributes().toString());
    return Mono.just("OK");
}
```

We are using reactive Spring Boot and we have replaced our controllers with RouterFunction. We are wondering how above feature - Authorization and get the token in our router method calls.

```
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
    return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/hello"), helloHandler::testHello);
}
```

When we tried passing the `JwtAuthenticationToken` in the router method call, it threw

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'JwtAuthenticationToken' type found.

```
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/hello"), helloHandler::testHello);
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerRequest.Headers.html

you are passing the request to the handler, you can get the bearer token from there(btw as a general rule secure, httpOnly cookie with csrf token is a better way to pass the jwt),
otherwise you need to switch to the non functional implementation of webflux there you can  get the headers in the old way , your solution will of course not work as the RouterFunction is a bean initiation method and has nothing to do with when request is triggered

Comment: Thanks Roie Beck for your comment. It helped understand the wrong doing of trying to get token at Bean initiation method. On the ServerRequest.Headers part, I can get the token from it and need to parse it to get the claims set. If there is other to convert the token to JWTAuthenticationToken, I can overcome this parse scenario and directly validate claimsset from JWTAuthenticationToken. Any suggestions here

Answer (score 0):

We came up this solution if it makes any sense, or valid. We ran into same issue lately as we began a journey of converting our legacy and synchronous spring boot server app to an asynchronous one. The JwtAuthenticationToken which we use to get some added attribute to the token used by the system works out of the box when we used the RestController and pass it as an argument in the protected endpoint method. But with Router Function we could not get it to work. After 1 day of painstaking research on google, stackoverflow, spring's reactive application resource server docs, we could not get any head way. However, this post got us thinking even more. so we came up with this solution:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FitnessAccountWebHandler {
    private final FitnessAccountService accountService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAccountByUserId(ServerRequest request) {
        String userId = request.pathVariable(AccountResourceConfig.USER_ID);
        // This will give you the JwtAuthenticationToken if a Principal is 
        // returned or empty if no authentication is found
        Mono<JwtAuthenticationToken> authentication = request
                .principal()
                .cast(JwtAuthenticationToken.class);

        return authentication.flatMap(auth -> {
            log.info("Subject: {}", auth.getName());
            return accountService.getSomething(userId)
                    .flatMap(ServerResponse.ok()::bodyValue)
                    .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
        });

    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone and save some time.